# How to resolve Avoid an excessive DOM size error in react js

Tags: reactjs, dom

I am a react js developer,

Now currently working on application's performance at that time I am getting Avoid an excessive DOM size error in lighthouse. How to resolve it.
[Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohyYH.png)

How to reduce the DOM Size here.

Comment: Why are you generating so many DOM elements?